# specify rosbag save path in launchfile

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, roslaunch, rosbag, bagfile

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I'm trying to specify the path to which my rosbag files will be written to. The call to launch the datalogging is happening in the launch file.
The issue I'm having is I want it to be repeatable on other peoples machines so I don't want to have to include the full file path. ie `/home/doug/catkin_ws/src/bagfiles/chatter` something like `/home/(find user)/catkin_ws/src/bagfiles/chatter` would be ideal.

the whole section of code that calls rosbag in the launchfile.

```
<arg name="data_log" default="true" />

  <group if="$(arg data_log)">
    <arg name="topics_logged" default="/chatter"/>

    <node pkg="rosbag" type="record" 
    args="-o /home/doug/catkin_ws/src/bagfiles/chatter /chatter" name="record" output="screen"/>
  </group>
```

Thanks for any help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/362819/specify-rosbag-save-path-in-launchfile/) by [TheMilkman92](https://answers.ros.org/users/60334/themilkman92/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2020-10-04

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the `$(env ...)` [substitution arg](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML#substitution_args).

So

```
<node pkg="rosbag" type="record" 
args="-o /home/$(env USER)/catkin_ws/src/bagfiles/chatter /chatter" name="record" output="screen"/>
```

Then again, that user would need to have the directory structure `~/catkin_ws/src/bagfiles/chatter` present. I suggest to use something that is definitiely available, i.e. either directly storing into the home directory, or something read-writable by any user...

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2020-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-10-05**:\

> Then again, that user would need to have the directory structure `~/catkin_ws/src/bagfiles/chatter` present.

Exactly. This is only a partial solution I would say.

> I suggest to use something that is definitiely available, i.e. either directly storing into the home directory, or something read-writable by any user...

why not use a `roslaunch` `arg` and specify the full path when starting the `.launch` file?

**Comment by [TheMilkman92](https://answers.ros.org/users/60334/themilkman92/) on 2020-10-05**:
@mgruhler Thanks for you help! You should change the `($env USER)` to `$(env USER)` in your response. otherwise that works perfectly!

@gvdhoom That's completely fair, but it would be a rare case that someone would call the workspace something other than catkin_ws right? I can just put that in our documentation. Unless, is there another directory that would make more sense for something like this?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-10-05**:\

> but it would be a rare case that someone would call the workspace something other than catkin_ws right?

no, that's not rare at all.

At this moment I have 43 workspaces, none of which are called `catkin_ws`.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2020-10-06**:\

> You should change the `($env USER)` to `$(env USER)` in your response.

@TheMilkman92 whoops, you are right. Sorry about that.

> no, that's not rare at all.

I totally agree with @gvdhoorn (though I don't have THAT many workspaces :-D ). I never call my workspaces `catkin_ws`. This is merely something like a "tutorial convention"...

**Comment by [TheMilkman92](https://answers.ros.org/users/60334/themilkman92/) on 2020-10-08**:
I see @gvdhoorn and @mgruhler, I'll put it outside the workspace in the USER directory. Thanks for the help!